# Reusing an angularjs directive, but making changes to it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I find myself in a situation where I'm using 90% of a custom directive I previously wrote, but I need 10% to be different in my new scenario/case.  I was thinking I could do one of two things:

1) make a directive of the 10% (seems like it might be overkill in my case).

2) write an ng-click in the directive html tag and pass in a string for the scenario, like

`<directive ng-click="whichOne("scenario1")"> </directive>`

and in my controller

```
    function whichOne(scenario) {
      if (scenario === 'scenario1') {
       ctrl.showThings = true;
    }
      if (scenario === 'scenario2') {
      ctrl.showThings = false;
   }
    // do something else for other scenarios...hide or show different divs
    }
```

and in my directives template:

```
<div class="thingIWantToShow" ng-show="ctrl.showThings"> Thing </div>
```

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you specifically trying to add a click handler to an element, to toggle a show/hide variable? Is `ng-click` the directive you want 90% of, or is it another directive -- and if so, which one?

Comment: I would like to show/hide certain parts of the HTML and would just be using a variable in my controller to do so in my example. I'm referring to a custom directive, any custom directive that I make. I updated my question to make it a little bit clearer

Comment: If you want to interact with your controller (i.e. not the directive's controller) and specifically want to do something on click, then use `ng-click`; that's exactly what it is for. If your custom directive has a controller and you want to interact with that, write another controller and use the require option to access the directive's controller in your link function.

Comment: Alternatively, maybe the custom directive that you need 90% of could be refactored to accept an attribute (ex: `show-things="true"`)?

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking along the lines of your last comment, i.e. isolate scope

Comment: If you can provide a concrete example in the form of a JSFiddle or something similar, I can offer a better answer to your question.